# Is there a way to modify JSF component libraries in Netbeans without having to constantly undeploy/clean/rebuild/deploy?

Tags: jsf, netbeans

We have several web applications that use a separate JSF component library in a separate Netbeans project  The issue with this is that, every time we make a change to the JSF component library in development, we have to completely rebuilt both that project and the project that is using it because the JSF component library is in a jar)

If the JSF components were within the web application itself, then any changes to static files would be instant.  Any changes to Java code would just required recompile/redeploy.

Does anyone have an elegant solution for this other than moving the JSF component library back into the web applications?

Comment: What is that "*separate JSF component library*" and that "*separate NetBeans project*"? When you replace an existing JAR with another JAR within an IDE, those changes will not automatically be propagated to the deployed WAR / EAR which resides in the server itself and hence, completely unaware of the presence of any IDE. In order to make those changes propagate to the WAR / EAR, redeploying the application is necessary, whenever such changes are made. This should be affordable and acceptable as replacing libraries is only occasionally necessary.

Comment: Our component library is in a java project that is jar'd up.  This jar is used by several web applications.  This library is constantly evolving, though, so  developing it and testing it within one of the using web apps is desirable.  If they were directly within the web app, though, then modifying static pages happens instantly (no re-deploy needed).  Also, not sure if this is a glassfish limitation, but being inside a jar requires a full app server reboot cuz the old jar code seems to get "stuck".

Comment: As to the last statement, it is not related to the server in question. It is related to the target IDE only as only the IDE is responsible for taking necessary steps, whenever it finds something being changed internally or externally. The server knows absolutely nothing about the presence of an IDE being used. I observed that several times but yet found no way nor I am hoping a way as it is very unlikely.

Comment: No idea about Netbeans, but Eclipse can hotdeploy stuff to a certain degree (only method body changes) when library is included as another project in same workspace and is associated as deployment assembly of main project or via Maven automatic workspace resolution. JRebel makes it even better by hotdeploying a.o. brand new methods.

Comment: Hmm, there seems to be a JRebel plugin for Netbeans that may enable this.  I will definitely check that out and see if it works (Thanks for the tips @Tiny/@BalusC)